# In python I'd like to eliminate some dictionary items ({n:[0,0]}) in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

d is the list of dictionaries, the items I want to remove from the list are: {3: [0, 0]},{5: [0, 0]}, {6: [0, 0]}, {7: [0, 0]}, {8: [0, 0]}.

Here's my failed attempt:

```
    d=[{1: [2.9, 1.04]}, {2: [1.45, 1.01]}, {3: [0, 0]}, {4: [9.5, 1.55]}, {5: [0, 0]}, {6: [0, 0]}, {7: [0, 0]}, {8: [0, 0]}]
    for i,v in enumerate(d):
        if v[i+1] == [0,0]: d.pop(i)
    File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
    KeyError: 3
```

Please help.

Comment: dictionary doesn't suppourt enumerate, you can do d.iteritems(), in which case `if item==[0,0]: d.pop(key)`

Comment: In  the problem described, d is a list which does support enumerate, as mentioned "d is the list of dictionaries"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is a list of dictionaries. Iterating over a list and changing it is a bad idea. Use a list comprehension to filter out the undesirable items instead:

```
out = [i for i in d if list(i.values())[0] != [0,0]]
```

Output:

```
[{1: [2.9, 1.04]}, {2: [1.45, 1.01]}, {4: [9.5, 1.55]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for v in d[:]:
    if [0,0] in v.values():
        d.remove(v)
```